# Are there any good ways to express conditional ownership on ERC20 or ERC721 tokens?

Tags: solidity, contract-design, erc-20, erc-721

I'm currently looking for any good ways to express conditional ownership on tokens.
I look into `approve` function of both ERC20/ERC721 but, it seems that function may be disapproved by the owner and people approved don't have any right to prevent the owner to transfer tokens.

the needs for spec are below.

- one account (account A) can be seen as an owner of a token so that they can use them in other services(e.g. using its right to receive dividends)
- other accounts (lets say secondary owners) can prevent A to transfer token to others on Dex or any other services alike.

Answer (score 1):

> one account (account A) can be seen as an owner of a token so that they can use them in other services(e.g. using its right to receive dividends)

This you can implement with the existing interface as is and perhaps with a new function to calculate dividend.

> other accounts (lets say secondary owners) can prevent A to transfer token to others on Dex or any other services alike.

In this case you can store a list of accounts that need to approve so that A is able to spend tokens. All or a specific number of the approvers have to call a function that registers their approval for the spending request before A can spend. But storing such a list in your token contract can be cumbersome. You can better create a different contract that deals with these requirements. That contract will hold A's tokens and wait for secondary owners approval before A can spend the tokens.